# Image Link replace with other link JS

Tags: javascript, replace

I have html tag of img

```
<img id="photo" src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nt2iZrVQYZE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/z6WGWyexYpM/s512-c/photo.jpg">
```

for changing s512-c to s36-c i am using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
var orgImg = document.getElementById('photo');
orgImg.src = orgImg.src.replace('s512-c', 's36-c');
})();
//]]>
</script>
```

but this is replacing only one id="photo" to

```
<img id="photo" src="//lh5.googleusercontent.com/-nt2iZrVQYZE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/z6WGWyexYpM/s36-c/photo.jpg"/>
```

I want to change all image link s512-c to s36-c.
help me.

Comment: There must be only one `id="photo"` in your document - IDs are required to be unique, and `getElementById` will return only one (or no) element. Use a class instead.

Comment: And this is valid. IDs should be used only once!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the images (by [tag name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName)) instead of getting the image by id.  I'll also note that each DOM element id should be unique; you cannot assign the same id to more than one image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        var orgImg = images[i];
        orgImg.src = orgImg.src.replace('s512-c', 's36-c');
    }
})();
</script>
```

If your page has more images on it than need to be modified, you might want to assign a class to the ones that do and use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id in a single page. What you should do is either retrieve your images by their tag names (img) or give them a class name and retrieve them with it. Since you're using jquery, here's a solution with jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/DVS67/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").each(function(index, elem) {
        $(elem).attr("src", $(elem).attr("src").replace('s512-c', 's36-c'));
    });
});
```

If you decide to use class names, simply replace de selector `$("img")` by `$(".yourclassname")`

Comment: any jquery required for this...?

Comment: No problem, you should accept this as your answer if it resolved your problem ;)

Answer (score -2):

You should use different ids for each img.
You also can add a class to all the imgs you want to change and then change them with jquery